# GPU usage in OpenGL shoots up when program ends

Tags: windows, performance, graphics, 3d, gpu

I'm working on a 3D graphics program using PyOpenGL. When I watch the GPU usage on windows task manager, it goes up to around 20% when I begin the program, and then remains arounds 15% while the program is running. When I close the program, it goes up to 100% for just a second, and then drops down to 0%.
[image: GPU During Program]
Why is the GPU going way up when the program ends, and is this an issue with the program? When I run a 2d graphics program with pygame, there is no spike.